# Android media recorder records only my voice

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, phone-call

When I try to record my phone calls. in some device it records only my voice.
here is the code:

```
private MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
```

As you can see the media source is set to: `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL`

Why it is that?

Comment: you can try recoding use `mediarecorder.audiosource.mic` instead of `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` because MIC will work on most of device for recoding down/up link voice

Comment: I'm pretty sure `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` is disabled on purpose. This is because recording a voice call without the person that is being recorded knowing about it is against the law in most countries.

Comment: @Paul: I've worked on several Android phones and I can tell you that we've never crippled voice call recording on purpose. Sometimes the platform that the device is based on comes with some limitations, and then you have to ask yourself which features to prioritize, which means that some problems will remain unsolved. I suspect that's what happened here, even without knowing which devices the OP is referring to in his question.

Comment: Did anyone solve the issue? I have a similar problem.